# Trouble drawing 3d-style effect

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+

I've been racking my brain trying to figure out how to animate an effect.  This is related to a question I asked on math.stackexchange.com.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91120/equal-division-of-rectangles-to-make-total/

As a side note, I didn't implement the drawing algorithm that was defined on the question above -- instead using my own in order to change the perspective to make it look more condensed.

I've been able to draw a stationary 3d style effect, but I am having trouble wrapping my brain around the logic to make the lines below look like they are coming towards you.

[image]

My code is as follows,

```
        List<double> sizes = new List<double>();
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int y = 1; y < 10; y++)
            {
                double s = ((240 / 2) / y) / 4;
                sizes.Add(s);
            }
            sizes.Add(0);
        }

        int offset = 0;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Bitmap b = new Bitmap(320, 480);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b);

            Color firstColor = Color.DarkGray;
            Color secondColor = Color.Gray;    
            Color c = firstColor;

            int yOffset = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < sizes.Count; i++)
            {
                c = (i % 2 == 0) ? firstColor : secondColor;

                int y = (int)Math.Round(b.Height - yOffset - sizes[i]);
                int height = (int)Math.Round(sizes[i]);

                g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(c), new Rectangle(0, y + offset, b.Width, height + offset));
                yOffset += (int)sizes[i];
            }

            this.BackgroundImage = b;
            offset+=1;
        }
```

Each button click should cause the rectangles to resize and move closer.  However, my rectangles aren't growing as they should.  My logic draws fine, but simply doesn't work as far as moving goes.

So my question is:

Is there an existing algorithm for this effect that I am not aware of, or is this something pretty simple that I'm over thinking?  Any help in correcting my logic or pointing me in the right direction would be very appreciated.

Comment: Unrelated side note, you create three different disposable resources on each click.  Try wrapping them in a "using" statement, and dispose of the old BackgroundImage when replacing it with a new one.

Comment: @Moozhe -- This is just throw away code (as noted by button1 and Form1) to get the logic in place, so I'm not really overly concerned about the performance. The final product will be developed in iOS. I'm just trying to hammer out the general drawing algorithm. :)

Comment: @George I did what I can - there's my answer that might satisfy you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting...

(video of the answer here: http://youtu.be/estq62yz7v0)

I would do it like that:

First, drop all RECTANGLE drawing and draw your effect line by line.  Like so:

```
for (int y=start;y<end;y++) 
{
    color = DetermineColorFor(y-start);
    DrawLine(left, y, right, y, color);
}
```

This is of course pseudo-code not to be troubled with GDI+ or something.

Everything is clear here, except on how to code `DetermineColorFor()` method.  That method will have to return color of the line at specified PROJECTED height.
[image: projection diagram]

Now, on the picture, you have:

- you point of view (X) - didn't know how to draw an eye
- red line (that's your screen - projection plane)
- your background (alternating stripes at the bottom)
- and few projecting lines that should help you devise the `DetermineColorFor()` method

Hint - use triangle similarity to go from screen coordinates to 'bar' coordinates.
Next hint - when you are in 'bar' coordinates, use modulo operator to determine color.

I'll add more hints if needed, but it would be great if you solved this on your own.

---

I was somehow inspired by the question, and have created a code for the solution.  Here it is:

```
int _offset = 0;
double period = 20.0;
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int y = Height / 3; y < Height; y++)
    {
        using (Graphics g = CreateGraphics())
        {
            Pen p = new Pen(GetColorFor(y - Height / 3));
            g.DrawLine(p, 0, y, Width, y);
            p.Dispose();
        }
    }
    _offset++;
}

private Color GetColorFor(int y)
{
    double d = 10.0;
    double h = 20.0;
    double z = 0.0;
    if (y != 0)
    {
        z = d * h / (double)y + _offset;
    }
    double l = 128 + 127 * Math.Sin(z * 2.0 * Math.PI / period);
    return Color.FromArgb((int)l, (int)l, (int)l);
}
```

Experiment with:

- `d` - distance from the eye to the projection screen
- `h` - height of the eye from the 'bar'
- `period` - stripe width on the 'bar'

I had a timer on the form and event properly hooked.  Timer duration was 20ms.

Comment: Very cool solution -- however, is it possible to prevent the gradient effect and have the solid lines like in my screen shot in the original question?

Comment: `if (l <= 128) {l = 0;} else {l = 255;}` =P

Comment: Exactly :)  you can even drop Sin() out, if you want some kind of speedup at that level.

Comment: Thanks for the help -- you thought of it from a completely different perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you're talking here about 2D rendering, as much as I understodd, to me it seems that you're gonna to reenvent the wheel. Cause what you need, IMHO; is use [Matrix Transformations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536397%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) already available in GDI+ for 2D rendering.

Example of aplying it in GDI+ :  [GDI+ and MatrixTranformations](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/matrix_transformation.aspx)

For this they use [System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.matrix.aspx) class, which is inside [Graphics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx).

The best ever 2D rendering framework I ever used is [Piccolo2D](http://code.google.com/p/piccolo2d/) framework which I used with great success in big real production project. Definitely use this for your 2D rendering projects, but first you need to study it little bit.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks -- but I'm looking for a algorithm to use that isn't framework specific.  Even if I could implement it in .NET, I don't know how well I'd be able to move that over to iOS.

Comment: @George: so definitely relay on Matrix tranformations of GDI+. They are not complicated, and much more reliable then just an algorithm, cause there are years of math behind that stuff.

Comment: You so don't need Matrix transformations of any kind.  The problem is interesting and has to me tackled in 2d domain only.

Comment: @DanielMošmondor: you use 2D matrix transformations. MT is not *only* about 3D. Actually *GDI+ Graphics* matrix *are* for 2D transform

Comment: @Tigran yes, you are correct here, but I feel (gut feeling) that it should be solved by hacking, not mathematics.  Let me try it in an answer form...

Comment: @DanielMošmondor: the good of *Microsoft* (or bad :), is that math is hidden. It's not absolutely so hard, and you do not need some deep matrix transformation or quaternion manipulation understanding. Just call functions like *Scale*, *Rotate*, *Move* with or even without specifying matrix but actual values. Don't say it's easy, but definitely no so diffcult as it seems. Wotkiing with *OpenGL* or any other CAD library is faaaar more complicated.

Comment: @Tigran I added my reasoning in a form of an answer, did a little picture too.  Hope it will help the OP...